# ¿Cómo solucionar que una subconsulta no me regrese más de un valor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Soy un estudiante de la carrera de sistemas informáticos, y en mi clase de administración de base de datos me pidieron realizar un trigger que actualizara la calificación final de forma automática al actualizar alguna de las calificaciones parciales. Mi base de datos es la siguiente:

```
create table alumno
(Id_A  smallint not null identity(1,1) constraint id_A_pk primary key,
Nombre_alum  char(20), App_Alum  char(20), Apm_Alum  char(20),  
edad_alum smallint, sexo_alum char(1), ID_c smallint, 
id_gpo smallint, fec_nac datetime)
go

create table Materia
(ID_M smallint not null constraint ID_M_pk primary key,
Nombre_Materia char (35), id_c smallint,cuatrimestre tinyint)
go

create table Calificacion
(Id_A  smallint constraint calificacion_id_A_FK references alumno(Id_A), 
ID_M smallint constraint calificacion_id_M_FK references materia(ID_M),
calif_1 decimal, calif_2 decimal, 
calif_3 decimal, calif_4 decimal, 
calif_f decimal, ano smallint, Periodo tinyint)
go

create table Carrera
(ID_c smallint identity(100,10) constraint id_c_PK primary key,
Nombre_carrera char(30))
go

create table grupo
(id_gpo smallint not null identity(1,1) constraint ID_g_Pk primary key,
Nombre_gpo char(6))

create table profesor
(Id_p smallint identity(1,1) constraint profesor_id_p_Pk Primary key, 
nombre_prof char(20), app_prof char(20), apm_prof char(20),
edad_prof tinyint, sexo_prof char(1), Id_jefe smallint,
id_c smallint constraint profesor_id_c_FK references carrera(id_c))
go

create table prof_gpo
(Id_gpo smallint constraint Prof_gpo_id_gpo_fk references grupo(id_gpo), 
id_p smallint constraint Prof_gpo_id_p_fk references profesor(id_p),
aula char(4))
go

alter table alumno
add constraint alumno_ID_c_FK foreign key (id_c)
references carrera(id_c)
go

alter table alumno
add constraint alumno_ID_gpo_FK foreign key (id_gpo)
references grupo(id_gpo)
go

alter table materia
add constraint materia_id_c_Fk foreign key(id_c) references carrera(id_c)
go

alter table profesor
add constraint profesor_Id_jefe_FK foreign key(Id_jefe) 
references profesor(Id_p)
go
```

Y mi disparador es el siguiente:

```
Alter trigger tg_promAlu
On Calificacion
After Update
    As
        Begin
            Declare @cveAlu smallint = (Select Id_A from inserted)
            Declare @cveMat smallint = (Select ID_M from inserted)
            Declare @prom decimal = (Select AVG(calif_1+calif_2+calif_3+calif_4)
                                                            From Calificacion Where Id_A = @cveAlu and ID_M = @cveMat)
            Where Id_A = @cveAlu and ID_M = @cveMat

            Declare @promPrint varchar(5) = convert(varchar(5),@prom)
            Print 'El promedio del alumno es: ' + @promPrint
        End
Go
```

Y el error que me muestra es el siguiente:

> Mens 512, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Procedimiento tg_promAlu, Línea 6
>   La subconsulta ha devuelto más de un valor, lo que no es correcto cuando va a continuación de =, !=, <, <=, >, >= o cuando se utiliza como expresión.
>   Se terminó la instrucción.

Comment: Sé que ya aceptastes una respuesta, pero creo que todavía hay un punto clave que no has entendido del todo en cuanto a cómo funcionan los disparadores en SQL Server. ¿Cual fue la sentencia que causó el error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es fácil arreglarlo, solo debes usar `top 1`, pero hay que ver si tienes los filtros correctos.

Por ejemplo, yo intentaria cambiar esta consulta:

`Declare @cveAlu smallint = (Select Id_A from inserted)`

Por algo como esto:

`Declare @cveAlu smallint = (Select top 1 Id_A from inserted)`

De esta manera solo te regresará un registro.  Ahora si quieres el último, supongo que podrías ordenarlo de forma descendente:

`Declare @cveAlu smallint = (Select top 1 Id_A from inserted order by Id_A desc)`

Así podrías ir cambiando cada sub-consulta asegurándote de que solo regrese un valor ya se con `top 1` o mejorando tus filtros.

Comment: Muchas gracias, tenias razón. fue suficiente con agregar el top 1 en las sub-consultas.

Comment: Pero tienes que validar que la información sea la correcta, puede ser error de DATOS... para asegurarte que la información se estará actualizando correctamente.  Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Aunque introducir un `TOP 1`, en efecto, elimina el error que recibes, eso simplemente resuelve el síntoma ignorando el verdadero problema. Estoy convencido que esa solución no es adecuada en este caso, y te va a causar problemas con tus datos.

### ¿Cuál es el verdadero problema?

Lo primero, es importante entender *por qué* recibistes el error. El error sucede porque la tabla temporal `inserted` contiene más de un registro. Esto sucede cuando ejecutas una sentencia `update` que afecta más de un registro a la vez en la tabla `Calificacion`.

Relacionado a este punto, es importante recordar que, diferente a otras base de datos, en SQL Server, cuando ejecutas una sentencia SQL que afecta varios registros, el disparador dispara *una sola vez para todos los registros afectados*. De modo que para diseñar un disparador correctamente, debes poder manejar varios registros a la vez.

Nota lo que dice la referencia MSDN siguiente al respecto: [Crear desencadenadores DML para administrar varias filas de datos](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms190752.aspx):

> Cuando escriba el código para un desencadenador DML, tenga en cuenta que la instrucción que hace que se active el disparador puede ser una sola instrucción que afecte a varias filas de datos, en lugar de una sola fila. Este comportamiento es habitual para los desencadenadores `UPDATE` y `DELETE`, ya que estas instrucciones suelen afectar a varias filas.

Esa es tu falla. Tu disparador asume que solo vas a manejar un solo registro a la vez. Y el usar `TOP 1` solo te sirve para esconder la realidad y crear una ilusión de que aún puedes manejar un registro a la vez. Pero, haciendo esto, estás ignorando registros que deberías manejar.

### Otros problemas

1. Un detalle en apariencia menor, pero importante para poder diseñar un disparador multi-registros correctamente: necesitar definir una clave primaria en tu tabla `Calificacion`. No veo que tengas una. Deduzco que se supone que la combinación `Id_A, Id_M` es única, pero no lo has definido explícitamente.
2. Otro problema es que no estás usando la función [`AVG()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177677.aspx) correctamente. Al hacer:

   ```
   Select AVG(calif_1+calif_2+calif_3+calif_4)
   ```

   ... parece que estás bajo la impresión que eso te va a dar el promedio de las 4 calificaciones. Esto no es el caso en absoluto. [`AVG(expresión)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms177677.aspx) te devuelve el promedio de una expresión de entre varios registros. Pero como solo estás manejando un solo registro, en realidad solo estás sumando las 4 calificaciones sin hacer un promedio. Pero que veas el problema, [aquí te dejo un enlace para que veas el resultado de ejecutar `select avg(100 + 100 + 100 + 100)`](http://rextester.com/RHO60867).
3. Si la idea es de mantener al día el campo `calif_f` automáticamente, sería bueno que el trigger dispare también con las sentencias `INSERT`.

### Solución

Tomando en cuenta el propósito de tu trigger:

> me pidieron realizar un trigger que actualizara la calificación final de forma automática al actualizar alguna de las calificaciones parciales.

... yo ajustaría los puntos siguientes:

1. Formalizar `Id_A, ID_M` como la clave primaria de la tabla `Calificacion` (si la clave primaria debería definirse con otras columnas, no es un problema, pero requiere que se ajusta la condición en el join del trigger, ver más abajo).
2. Modificar el trigger para que dispare con los `INSERT`s también
3. Corregir el diseño del trigger para que maneje varios registros correctamente. Esto se logra haciendo un `join` con la tabla temporal `inserted`.
4. Corregir el cálculo del promedio. Para hacerlo correctamente, y manejando los `NULL` de la forma estándar, la sentencia se complica un poco con expresiones `CASE`, pero esa es la forma correcta de hacerlo, no usando la función `AVG()`.
5. Optimización: agregar una condición que solo pone al día el promedio si al menos uno de los campos `calif_N` fue modificado. Esto también sirve de protección para evitar disparos recursivos si el servidor está configurado para permitirlos.

El trigger corregido sería:

```
create trigger tg_promAlu
On Calificacion
After insert, Update
As
Begin
    set nocount on;

    if update(calif_1)
         or update(calif_2)
         or update(calif_3)
         or update(calif_4)
    update c
       set c.calif_f = case when i.calif_1 is not null
                              or i.calif_2 is not null
                              or i.calif_3 is not null
                              or i.calif_4 is not null
                            then
                              (coalesce(i.calif_1, 0)
                              + coalesce(i.calif_2, 0)
                              + coalesce(i.calif_3, 0)
                              + coalesce(i.calif_4, 0))
                              /
                              (case when i.calif_1 is null then 0 else 1 end
                               + case when i.calif_2 is null then 0 else 1 end
                               + case when i.calif_3 is null then 0 else 1 end
                               + case when i.calif_4 is null then 0 else 1 end)
                            end
      from inserted i
      join Calificacion c
        on c.Id_A = i.Id_A
       and c.ID_M = i.ID_M;
End;
Go
```

Si quieres ver el trigger en acción: <kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/QFQN90603)</kbd>